# Implement Hash Table using list variables in python

Tags: python, list, data-structures, hashtable

I implemented a simple hash table using list variables. Below is my code.

```py
hash_table = list([0 for i in range(8)])

def get_key(data):
    return hash(data)

def hash_function(key):
    return key % 8

def save_data(data, value):
    hash_address = hash_function(get_key(data))
    hash_table[hash_address] = value
    
def read_data(data):
    hash_address = hash_function(get_key(data))
    return hash_table[hash_address]
```

After putting some data into the hash table, I found something strange.

```py
save_data('Andy', '01055553333')
save_data('Dave', '01044443333')
save_data('Trump', '01022223333')

read_data('Dave')
```

The above code is to read Dave's value after putting data and value in the hash table.

And, this is my result.

```py
'01022223333'
```

But somehow, the result was Trump's value. So, I checked the entire hash table, but I couldn't find Dave's value.

```py
hash_table
```

```py
[0, 0, 0, '01055553333', 0, '01022223333', 0, 0]
```

I thought this was caused by the size of the hash table. But after increasing the size from 8 to 100, it still doesn't include Dave's value.

Or, is this problem caused by hash collision?

I want to know why this happened, and how to fix this problem.

Comment: *is this problem caused by hash collision?* What are the results of `hash('Dave')` and `hash('Trump')`?

Comment: Each result of `hash('Dave')`and `hash('Trump')` is `3202915769870683525` and `8707415080054204637`.

Comment: `3202915769870683525 % 8 = 5` and `8707415080054204637 % 8 = 5`. Do you see the problem?

Comment: Could it be considered that Dave's key and Trump's key are the same so that Dave's value is overwritten with Trump's value?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what is happening.